# What is cdpfs_notify_metadata_mod?

Tags: macos, mac

`dmesg` on my MacBook with Mac OS X 10.5.7 gives me a bunch of lines like this (with different file names):

```
cdpfs_notify_metadata_mod(365): cdpfs_get_zone_entry returned NULL 
entry: /Users/ljosa/tmp/emacs/nextstep/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/ 
share/emacs/23.1.50/lisp/wdired.el!!!
```

(The file at the end of the message is one that has recently been 
modified.)  I suspect that this has to do with either Time Machine or 
Atempo LiveBackup (or even Tivoli Storage Manager, which I used before, but should be gone from my system now).  However, googling for `cdpfs_notify_metadata_mod` gives no 
clue as to what is going on and whether something is wrong.  Does 
anyone know?

Comment: This is belong to Server fault

Comment: @Krish: It's not server related. Why would it belong on Server Fault?

Comment: It belongs to Super User; it's not a problem related to a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cdpfs` most likely refers to a continuous data protection file system which is definitely not used with Time Machine.

The marketing to do with Atempo LiveBackup suggests it uses CDP in order to do it's backup but not having used or seen the product first hand I can't confirm this for sure. I can only tell you that nothing built into OS X is using CDP.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.  Perhaps it could also be a remnant of Tivoli Storage Manager, which we used before but was supposed to be gone from my system now?  (I updated my question and added a reference to TSM.)

Comment: Googling about cdpfs revealed that TSM uses it for it's backups as well. It's quite possible there is something left over.